# Java Class Instantiation with Block

Tags: java, instantiation

I have a base class such as this

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    protected Class<? extends iBase> _BASE = null;

    protected static abstract class iBase {}

    protected BaseClass() {
        setBase();
    }

    protected void setBase() {
        // use reflection to find fields, but...
        // _BASE is null?
    }
}
```

and extend it with a class such as this

```
public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    { // what is this called? Anonymous Block Class Statements?
        _BASE = iBase.class;
    } // does this get called before constructor starts?

    public static class iBase extends BaseClass.iBase { // yes, it is hiding super
        public static final String someValue = "";
    }

    public MyClass() {
        super();
    }
}
```

when I go to instantiate the new class

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

`_BASE` is null, why? I clearly set it

Comment: You could pass the class as an argument to the ```BaseClass``` constructor.

Comment: // what is this called? Anonymous Block Class Statements? - These are instance (as opposed to static) initialization blocks

Comment: @Dici cause with reflection I can get the subclass's fields, cause the parent sets none

Comment: But your field is on the parent class... you don't need reflection to access it. Anyway, not sure what you were trying to achieve. By the way, overridable methods called in a constructor are bad and dangerous practice

Comment: @Dici I was wanting the parent class to handle the implementation; which was basically reading what fields were available. I'm still not understanding why calling a method from a constructor is bad practice, if I can find a way to get _BASE set before it is called, then what would be the issue? Worst case you just can't instantiate the class, right?

Comment: There's a reason why the constuctor of the superclass is always called before the constructor of its subclasses. A subclass does not necessarily know about all the state held by the superclass, hence it should never execute any code before the superclass fields have been properly initiliazed. An overridable method called from a constructor is a gateway for subclasses to inject code in their superclass constructor, before the initialization is complete. That's why it's dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Because the superclass constructor is called **before** the subclass constructor. So `setBase()` is being executed before the block initailizing _BASE in the subclass.

Calling an overrideable method from a base class constructor is something you should avoid, precisely because of the problems you're facing with that practice. And also because if you override it in the subclass, the overridden implementation will be called on an object which is not properly initialized yet.

Comment: The debug doesn't show that; it shows _BASE being set, then the method executing when stepping through.

Comment: Then your debugger is wrong, or you don't interpret what it does correctly. Just add println statements everywhere, and you'll see (if the fact that _BASE is null is not enough to convince you).